# Numbered equation inside enumerate environment aligned with its item label

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, amsmath, enumerate, alignment

This is what I have:

[image]

and this is what I need (ignore the difference related to horizontal space in this picture):
[image]

That is, a numbered equation inside an enumerate environment and aligned with it's item label.

Some of my code is this:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
        \item \begin{gather}
            f^{(n)}(z_0) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i} \oint_C 
            \frac{f(z)dz}{(z - z_0)^{(n+1)}}
        \end{gather} 
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try with `\usepackage{mathtools}` and `\SwapAboveDisplaySkip` ?

Comment: No, I haven't try. How would you adapt the code to use it? I've never heard of that command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you (a) use inline math mode instead of a displayed equation environment and (b) place the equation number "by hand" at the right hand edge of the text block. If you need to typeset a multi-row equation in this manner, encase it either in `\begin{aligned}[t]` and `\end{aligned}` or in `\begin{gathered} and` \end{gathered}`.

The resulting equation can be cross-referenced using the usual `\label`-`\ref` (or `\eqref`) mechanism.

[image]

Remark: The frame lines at the edges of the text block are drawn because the `showframe` package is loaded.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe}  % place framebox around textblock
\newcommand\puteqnum{%    handy shortcut macro
  \refstepcounter{equation}\textup{(\theequation)}}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{2} % just for this example
\setcounter{equation}{7}

\null
\begin{enumerate}
\item \hfill % center the following material horizontally
      $\displaystyle    % <-- don't forget \displaystyle
            f^{(n)}(z_0) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i} \oint_C 
            \frac{f(z)\,dz}{(z - z_0)^{(n+1)}} $
      \hfill 
      \puteqnum \label{eq:oint} % place \label *after* \puteqnum
\end{enumerate}

A cross-reference to equation \eqref{eq:oint}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you!!